# Qt 5.12 Mac OS ugly font rendering

Tags: macos, qt, fonts

Running my Qt application on my MacBook Pro 2015 the application fonts look really ugly.

[image: Ugly fonts in Qt application on Mac OS Catalina]

Any ideas whats going on here?

Comment: Looks like high-resolution fonts are not enabled, how does your Info.plist look like?

Comment: I have this inside my .plist:

`<key>NSHighResolutionCapable</key>
        <string>True</string>`

Answer (score 0):

Have you this line in your main function ?

```
QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
```

Also read this page : https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/highdpi.html

> macOS and iOS
>
> The Apple platforms implement scaling and coordinate system
>   virtualization in the operating system. Normally, no special
>   configuration is required.
>
> On macOS, high-DPI support is enabled by settings in the Info.plist
>   file; so make sure these settings are present.

```
 <key>NSPrincipalClass</key> <string>NSApplication</string>
 <key>NSHighResolutionCapable</key> <string>True</string>
```

> Newer versions of qmake will generate an Info.plist file with the
>   NSPrincipalClass key; this is sufficient since NSHighResolutionCapable
>   is true by default.
>
> Note: Both macOS and iOS may apply further virtualization, such that
>   device pixels no longer correspond to display pixels 1:1. This happens
>   on the iPhone 6+ and on macOS configured with "display scaling"
>   enabled.

Comment: Note that the Info.plist is cached by macOS, so if you build your application and change the Info.plist afterwards, the changes might be ignored. That bit me a few times debugging issues like this. The quick workaround is to create a new build directory. (there's probably also a way to delete the cache somewhere)